# How can a user encrypt a configuration file to be used by a service application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, encryption

Ok, I'm asking a rather generic question to a specific problem. I have searched this in more ways than I can count, and nothing seems to work. Let me explain my need and then I'll mention a few of the best solutions I've found and why they don't work in my case.

I have an application that a user launches and uses to set up various configuration values that are saved into an `app.config` file. This is a WPF application. Specifically, some of this data are HIGHLY sensitive.

This data needs to encrypted and subsequently decrypted by a Windows Service that will be launched by the application once the configuration step is finished. The general solution given for this scenario is to use DPAPI, which has two modes for encryption: User and Local Machine.

If you use User-level encryption, your application will encrypt and decrypt data as much as it desires, *as long as the current user that initially encrypts the data is doing the decryption*. My problem is that when the service is started, it also restarts on reboots and will specifically be running under a different user account.

The next approach, using DPAPI, is to encrypt the data as the Local Machine.  This means that when ANYONE logs into the machine can decrypt the sensitive data.  This is a BIG no-no!

What I need is to have a way for a user to specify the data he wants to encrypt and then specify an account (in this case, what will be the service account) and use it for data encryption.

I can't find how to do this.  [This MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650304.aspx) alludes that can be done. (See section 'Web Farm Scenarios'.)  The TL;DR on that article is that for ASP.Net applications, you can use the `RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider` to encrypt your data, and export the keys to be used with a specific web account.  This is *close* to what I want, but in my case I need to create the data in a WPF application and store it to be used in a Windows Server Service.

How can this be done?

Comment: Hmm. I get where you're coming from, but in the end there's never going to be a way to COMPLETELY protect the information if it's stored on the machine. Who exactly do you need to protect this information from?

Comment: @s3raph86, that would be perfect but from my research, that's either not possible or documented at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish something similar to this using something as mundane as EFS, but unlike raw DPAPI, a recovery key might bypass the protection.  In either case, a local admin could replace your program with his own and it would have full access to the decrypted data.

As for setting this up, the easiest way to do that would be to interactively log on with the service account and either create the protected data using System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData or create a file in a directory marked with the "encrypt" attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the input. After further consideration this weekend I've made the recommendation that we use DPAPI but we give the user the choice of which setting to use. If they choose account-level security, I'll prompt them that they will need to setup the data using the service account that will run the service. We try to keep this app as simple as possible because the nature of it is pretty complex. However, security is of the utmost importance so I don't see a better approach then what I decided and you're suggesting. I'll give you the answer mark for your last suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use the account name as the salt for your encryption, decyption should use the logged in account name as the salt to decrypt.

Comment: Isn't that security by obsurity, which isn't really obscurity if the applucation uses .Net.  All an attacker would need is the account name/underlying ID to decrypt.

Answer (score 0):

i have a suggestion , you can create User group add required users into that group. And encrypt and decrypt data only if user is part of that group using second method.

Comment: You can't use a user group as a DPAPI context and, if you could, I'm not sure how that would be secured since encryption keys are derived from post-login user credential data.